# What are the advantages of Web Services over dynamic HTML?

Tags: php, web-services, web, dynamic-html

I was wondering what the advantages are of using an application server (e.g. glassfish) instead of providing content via a dynamic html page (e.g. PHP).  I'd like to understand the advantages of a 'web service', rather than simply a website, as I'm developing an online commerce site, and I am wondering what some rules of thumb might be for switching from straight Apache to something like glassfish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Application Servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) like Glassfish in the Java world usually refers to a software that additionally to just implementing a webserver runs your Java (or other JVM based language) web application in the context of the [Java Enterprise Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ee) specification. So it basically just a fancy Apache for web applications written in Java.
Rule of thumb: If you decide to use Java or another language that runs on the Java Virtual Machine and need or want to use any of the J2EE APIs you use an application server.

As a HTML page is normally a human readable representation of information a webservice provides information in a machine readable format so that machines can interact with each other by using the HTTP protocol. Instead of the general webservice concept, the term [Webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservice) is mostly used for a communication using the SOAP protocol. Since webservices are not language specific it doesn't matter if you are using PHP or Java or Ruby On Rails or whatever to implement the webservice. The decision if you want to provide a way to interact with an your web application other than just via a user operated webbrowser.

Comment: I see.. so is it necessary to make the interface public in order for it to be considered a web service?

Comment: Well, what I mean is that if I have a private interface, and I program to that, rather than an implementation, would this still be considered a web service?  Or is it merely APIs that are publicly available?

Comment: A webservice communicates via HTTP (there are exceptions but it is the usual protocol) and therefore offers a public interface by nature (although you might just use it internally). If you are talking about Java interfaces then they will of course have to be public.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop a web service, you are programming to an *interface*, not an *implementation*.  When you develop a page that is pushing out data that only your application understands how to consume, such as a proprietary html page, you are doing the exact opposite.

Think in broader terms of what you are trying to accomplish -- whether you will be implementing and reusing this service in multiple places, technologies, etc.  That's your key.

Comment: That's however <s>totally</s> mostly independent of what technology you decide to use. You can be programming to interface in PHP on Apache just as well as you could create clumsy web page running off Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of what style of web service.

are you comparing Soap to REST?

a REST web service is very similar to a web page as it uses all the inbuilt functionality of HTTP. Where as a SOAPrest service requires teh infrastructure required to read and digest it.

Glass fish ties you to a particular environment, which is meant to be wonderfully scalable and hassle free, but in reality is often not the case, requiring expensive resources to build and maintain the code. (not to mention infrastructure and liscences)

I would recommend using a very simple layer to produce your web service. eg: PHP and a small rest frame work, mabee something like a modified version of code igniter. Since rest is stateless, it makes it very easy to scale. Just add more apache web servers till the cows come hiome.. err.. or untill your database gets smashed.. but success always has its problems. Why not go with a REST implementation on the cloud. Put pup some micro instances Webservers on amazon, add an abstract relational databse, and off you go.

But as pointed out by others in this discusion you are not limited by language. better to decide on what your service is. REST or SOAP. a rest service can be built in Python, Java, Pearl PHP etc etc.. A SOAP rest service woukld probably be built in Java,a s all the cool tools are there.. which may mean glass fish.